# Using Messages in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to build a menu. I have multiple buttons that I need to move different directions depending on which button is pressed. I have each button sending a message to the empty that the buttons are parented to in order to move them, however, it will only play one of the animations I have set for them.Any help would be much appreciated! [image]

Comment: One of your controllers is set to `or` and the other to `and`.  Is that the problem?  I think they should both be `and`.

Comment: I have them both set to and, unfortunately, it didn't change anything

Comment: Your description tells your issue has nothing to do with messages. Otherwise you would not be able to see at at least one action playing. The behavior completely relies on how to play actions. [I suggest to trigger the actuators with keyboard sensors, to exclude side effects from messages]. I suggest to rephrase your question to mention the problem is action playing rather than messages.